# Unable to successfully perform GitPush or GetPushRef in cake script

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, cakebuild

I am attempting to use GitAliases to commit some changes to my Git repo from a cake script on Jenkins. I have been able to overcome the lack of descriptive information and examples for the methods and arguments in the documentation (https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/) for GitAdd(), GitCommit(), and GitTag(), all of which are working successfully now, but I am not able to get GitPush() nor GitPushRef() to work no matter what I try.

```
#addin "nuget:https://www.nuget.org/api/v2?package=Cake.Git";

using System;
using System.IO;

var gitUserName = Argument("gitUserName","userName");
var gitUserPassword = Argument("gitUserPassword","");
var gitEmail = Argument("gitEmail","some.user@domain.com");
var gitBranchName = Argument("gitBranchName","feature/test-git");


Task("Git:CommitAndPush")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        var rootPath = "./..";
        Information($"Commit and Push {rootPath}");

        Information("Staging all updated files in /available, /extracted, and /src directories...");
        var toAdd = new FilePath[]
        {
            new FilePath(Path.Combine(rootPath, "available")),
            new FilePath(Path.Combine(rootPath, "extracted"))
        };
        GitAdd(rootPath, toAdd);

        Information("Committing files...");
        var commit = GitCommit(rootPath, gitUserName, gitEmail, "Commit message");

        Information($"Pushing changes for commit {commit}...");

        // TODO: Cannot get any of these to work!
        //GitPush(rootPath);
        //GitPush(rootPath, gitUserName, gitUserPassword);
        //GitPush(rootPath, gitUserName, gitUserPassword, gitBranchName);

        //var gitTag = "myTag";
        //GitTag(rootPath, gitTag);
        //GitPushRef(rootPath, "origin", gitTag);
        //GitPushRef(rootPath, gitUserName, gitUserPassword, "origin", gitTag);

        Information("Git process complete!");
    });
```

I have tried every overload of GitPush() and GitPushRef() including creating a tag and pushing the tag using GitPushRef() but no luck. I can see the commit is successful locally, and the tag gets created, but the Push always fails. The most common error I am getting is:

"Error: One or more errors occurred.
    unsupported URL protocol"

The Git user account uses SSH.

Comment: Now that you have been able to overcome the lack of descriptive information and examples for the methods and arguments in the documentation, am I right in saying that you will be in a position to contribute back to help improve the documentation?  All of it is open source, and we would welcome any help that you can offer in this area.

Comment: Gary - I'll see if I can make some meaningful contribution to the documentation.

Comment: That is great news! I look forward to reviewing your PRs, and I am sure Mattias will welcome the additions.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find the source file for the documentation. Can you point me to it?

Comment: Depending on exactly which part of the page you are referring to, it it likely you are referring to the XML comments in the source files for the Cake_Git repository within the Cake-contrib GitHub Organisation.

Comment: As an example... https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake_Git/blob/develop/src/Cake.Git/GitAliases.Add.cs#L20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake Git uses libgit2sharp for git operations, which doesn't support SSH.

There's an open issue for it on libgit2sharp GitHub repo
https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1422

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'll have to create an account that does not use SSH and see if I can get that to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still am not able to get GitPush to succeed. I set up an account on Bitbucket.org to use a password (no SSH) and I am able to successfully clone the repo on my server (where Jenkins is running) using SourceTree, but Jenkins is unable to connect using that account (permission denied) and GitPush still fails (unsupported URL protocol). If i let Jenkins use my SSH account to clone the repo, then open that repo using SourceTree, it appears that it is not tracking a remote branch. Maybe that is why the GitPush fails? I need to figure out how to make it track the remote branch.